# png2ico exporting ICO in lower quality than the original PNGs

Tags: terminal, png, ico

I have 6 PNG files that I want to bundle into one ICO file.  I'd like to use something like [png2ico](http://www.winterdrache.de/freeware/png2ico/) instead of a web app like [ConvertICO.org's web app](http://convertico.org/Multi_Image_to_one_icon/).

When the ICO is produced using png2ico, the quality of the ICO seems to have dropped.  Below are 2 images (100% view and zoomed in) comparing the png2ico output (right) to the original PNG (left).

[image: Comparison of original PNG & png2ico's output.]

[image: Comparison of original PNG & png2ico's output magnified.]

Is this a limitation of png2ico?  Can I stop png2ico from lowering the quality?  Can you recommend another way of bundling 6 PNGs into 1 ICO using Terminal on OSX?

Comment: It appears that the alpha channel has been reduced to simple binary transparency, losing the antialiasing of the edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed the developer of [png2ico](http://www.winterdrache.de/freeware/png2ico/) and it sounds like png2ico only supports 256 colors which isn't acceptable for what I needed.  I have since discovered that [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) can convert and bundle multiple PNGs into one ICO thanks to [Rob W's post here](https://superuser.com/a/683203).